# Is there a weather-safe way to fill holes in cedar to enable re-attaching screws?

Tags: screws, fence, bolts, gates, gate-post

I have a fence and gate made out of cedar.  The gate was attached to a post with 2 large hinges, using 2" lag bolts for each hinge.  The top hinge had both bolts pull out of the post over several years.

Because of the dimensions, there isn't a way to adjust the hinge placement.  What are my options for reattaching?  Is there a way to fill the holes with something that would be weathersafe (Ohio - so heat, cold, rain, snow) and strong enough to use these same bolts again?

Comment: A picture of the damage would be most helpful. Did the bolts fail? Did the wood fail? Did the metal hinges fail? Without knowing those things, it's really hard to do much but guess.

Comment: The wood failed, leaving stripped holes.

Comment: I would really add that photo if I were you. Visuals jog memories and might help people figure out a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most use just wood glue and toothpicks(or similar) to fill holes.

I would use similar pieces but with cedar, either a spare piece or shave/cut toothpick size pieces from a hidden section.

Would also try to use longer lag screws for a better bite, 3 or 4 inches if possible or bolts/nuts.

Bolts and nuts with washers right though the wood will hold better than screws.

Comment: For a gate, I'd go with through holes, nuts & bolts, and washers on both sides. I wouldn't try to repair the wood.